# Proving a norm on the space of differentiable functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions, normed-spaces

I consider the space $C^1[a, b]$ of (complex) functions that are at least once differentiable on $[a, b]$. I want to show that

$$||f||_{C^1} := ||f||_\infty + ||f'||_\infty$$

defines a norm on $C^1[a, b]$.

Now it's easy to see that $||f||_{C^1}$ is non-negative, and that it's zero iff f = 0, and it can be easily shown that it's compatible with multiplication of a scalar. But so far I've been struggling with proving and understanding that the triangle inequality is valid indeed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$||f+g||_{C^1} = ||f'+g'||_{\infty} + ||f+g||_{\infty} \le$$$$ \le ||f'||_{\infty} +||g'||_{\infty} + ||f||_{\infty} +||g||_{\infty} = ||f||_{C^1} + ||g||_{C^1}$$
when the inequality comes from triangle inequality applied to $||\cdot ||_{\infty}$

Answer (score 1):

If $\|f\|_{C^1}=0$, then $\|f\|_{\infty}=0$ and $\|f'\|_{\infty}=0$. In particular,
$$0=\|f\|_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}|f\left(x\right)|$$
and thus $f$ is identically zero.

Then, for all $f,g\in\mathcal{C}^{1}\left(\left[a,b\right];\mathbb{R}\right)$, we have
$$\|f+g\|_{C^1}=\|f+g\|_{\infty}+\|f'+g'\|_{\infty}=\sup_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}|f\left(x\right)+g\left(x\right)|+\sup_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}|f'\left(x\right)+g'\left(x\right)|$$
$$\leq\sup_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}|f\left(x\right)|+\sup_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}|g\left(x\right)|+\sup_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}|f'\left(x\right)|+\sup_{x\in\left[a,b\right]}|g'\left(x\right)|$$
$$=\|f\|_{\infty}+\|g\|_{\infty}+\|f'\|_{\infty}+\|g'\|_{\infty}
=\|f\|_{C^1}+\|g\|_{C^1}.$$